# UITableView reloadData and cellForRowAtIndexPath - interruptable?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Let's assume there exists a `UITableView` called myTable. Let's say the following sequence of events occur --

1. Table is fully populated.
2. The data source is updated (in this case an sqlite3 db, but doesn't really matter), an NSNotifcation happens to indicate that there is new data, the main thread receives the notification and then calls [myTable reloadData].
3. myTable's UITableViewDataSource's `numberOfSectionsInTableView` gets called. Assume only 1 section.
4. myTable's UITableViewDataSource's `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` gets called.
5. Several `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`'s get called depending on the number of rows in the data source.

My question has to do with the interruptability of cellForRowAtIndexPath.

The question --

If a "reloadData" is called and cellForRowAtIndexPath's are getting called AND another reloadData comes in, will the cellForRowAtIndexPath's stop midstream and restart after the calls to numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberofRowsInSection?

Or will the new reloadData be queued, such that all of the cellForRowAtIndexPaths will finish BEFORE the numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection get called?

I've looked and have been unsuccessful in finding an answer to this question in docs or the net. I'm concerned that if the data store is updated while the cellForRowAtIndexPaths are "running", the numberOfSectionsInTableView can change which can result in the cellForRowAtIndexPath requesting data for a cell that's now out of range.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you should only call `reloadData` on the main thread and since by the time a call to `reloadData` is done, all of the visible cells have already been loaded, there is no problem to worry about. The second call to `reloadData` will be made after the 1st one is done.

Comment: So, reloadData will block until numberOfSectionsInTableView, numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath are called? (and thanks for your response).

Comment: Yes. It is simple to verify. Put breakpoints at those methods and call `reloadData`. You will see that when `reloadData` returns, everything is done. BTW - it's not that `reloadData` "blocks". It is simply a method that calls other methods.

Comment: Ok, great! Thanks for the clarification on "block". I will set the bp and test that when I'm in front of my mac later today. Seems simple now. Geez! :-) Great to get another perspective and direction. Much appreciated rmaddy and A-Live and Stack Overflow.

Comment: I just tried and the observation is that reload data will return after numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection is called.  cellForRowAtIndexPath is called afterward by subsequent calls by _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow. So, if reloadData returns right after the two calls, and a Notification to reloadData comes in during cellForRowAtIndexPath operations, than it seems like another reloadData /can/ execute. Am I wrong?

Comment: Or is it that since this is all happening in the main thread, the reloaddata will only happen after the main thread is done w/all cellForRowAtIndexPaths?(what A-Live stated). Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to be in the middle of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` when `reloadData` is called assuming they are  both called on the same (main) thread (having an async processing on background thread at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` seems meaningless).